# How do I integrate logging into .NET code contract

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I am trying to wrap my head around .NET's code contract. When using code contract, how do I log the assert causing the method in question to fail. For example, look at this code:

```
  Public IsMatch(string x, string, y) 
{ 

    Contract.Assert(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)); 
     Contract.Assert(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(y));

       return x == y;
 }
```

Let say `x = string.Empty`. This will cause the method to fail. How do I log that the assert cause the method above to fail. I can have many asserts such as this in a large app and it would be nice to know which one is the trouble-maker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using code contract, how do I log the assert causing the method in question to fail?

If you're talking about logging, I assume you mean at runtime rather than static verification.

The asserts raise exceptions when they fail.  You can write a try/catch block to log exceptions:

```
try
{
    bool result = SomeClass.IsMatch(x, y);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.Error(e.ToString()); // Use whatever logging mechanism here
    throw; // Note: Make sure you rethrow if you catch "Exception e"
}
```

This will get you the stack trace of the exception, which will point to the line where the assertion failed.

As Polity mentioned, you can also include a `userMessage` parameter on each assertion.  That way your logs will contain custom error messages in addition to the stack trace.

If you need a good `logger` class, look at [the NLog library](http://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks. This helps further explain Polity's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.aspx

Basically as a second parameter you can specify a message.

That said, Contract.Assert is farely primitive. Post conditions can better be checked using Contract.Requires since its a requirement for your method.

*Edit: Post conditions should ofcourse be pre conditions*

Comment: +1 since this is good advice.  I also added how to do the actual logging my answer.  Feel free to co-opt it into this answer if you wish, since it is fairly obvious stuff.